# Email sending times out on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, email, timeout

I noticed all of a sudden that any operation that has to do with sending email on my site returns with 504 server timeout page. Fortunately, the email gets sent but returns a 504 error.
I went further to create a php script in the root of my application just to send email
`<?php
try{
    mail('name@email.com', 'Testing Magento mail', 'Hello user. Did you get the mail?');
    echo 'Mail sent';
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}`

but got the same effect of timeout.
Mails were going fine prior to today and nothing was changed on the server. 
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved the issue. It has to do with the way my `etc/hosts` file was configured. I added this line to it.
`127.0.0.1 myServername myServername.localdomain`
and it worked.